# Nginx + Ruby on Rails with Passenger give back blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have deployed a new project as usual, using Rails 7.1, Ruby 3.2.2, Phusion Passenger and Nginx.

I have checked separately that all are well installed, but can't get the index to load.

Doing curl I get this. Any clue of what might be failing?

The red color is just covering IP. .

**Nginx file:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name gestion.cristaleriallerena.com;
  root /home/deploy/cristales/code/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  passenger_preload_bundler on;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name cristales_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }
}
```

The application in deployment loads fine, and it shows. The code is the same git version.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem solved. It seems that in 7.1 de default is config.force_ssl = true. Olders versions were not.

Since I was configuring my server without SSL, that was the problem.

Just turn it to false, and it will work.